# What's wrong with named pipes used between 2 processes (no. 3)?

Tags: bash, process, parallel-processing, named-pipes

After some 100's combinations I resulted to the following code that uses one process as a server with a pipe to read responses from clients, I call it 'london' function and it's pipe 'london_pipe' (I was very uncertain to call my pipe 'london' too because of naming conflicts ?).
Underneath, there are 2 clients each communicating with it's own pipe with the server to read data with. I followed the same naming conventions, naming the pipes with the name of the function that uses them for **reading**. So, 'berlin' is reading from 'berlin_pipe' etc.

The overall structure uses 1 pipe-to-1 client and 1 pipe for the server as follows:

```
london ----writes madrid pipe-------->
london <----reads london_pipe----<-  |
london ----writes berlin_pipe---> |  |
                                | ^  |
                                | |  |
berlin <---reads berlin_pipe--<-  |  |
berlin ----writes london_pipe-----|  |
                                  ^  |
                                  |  |
madrid ----writes london_pipe------  v
madrid <----reads madrid_pipe------<-
```

Now, when I run my code I face a very strange situation where my clients repeatedly read the empty string and -as I've structured my program-they respond sending false alarm to the server! When I added the if-clause (see comments at code) the problem disappeared!

Can anybody explain that strange behaviour of my pipes? or there is a kind of problem with the code itself?

Briefly, some clarifications:
the code

```
while true; do
.......
done 4<"$pipename"
```

works for all clients even if fd 4 repeatedly used to point to a different pipe each time.
Now the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -u failglob
shopt -s extglob nullglob dotglob

DIR=$( cd "$( dirname "$0" )" && pwd )

#the server
function london (){
   local i message answer london_pipe berlin_pipe madrid_pipe
   london_pipe=london_$RANDOM.$RANDOM.$RANDOM.$$
   madrid_pipe=madrid_$RANDOM.$RANDOM.$RANDOM.$$
   berlin_pipe=berlin_$RANDOM.$RANDOM.$RANDOM.$$
   cd $DIR
   mkfifo $london_pipe
   mkfifo $madrid_pipe
   mkfifo $berlin_pipe
   ( madrid $madrid_pipe $london_pipe ) &
   ( berlin $berlin_pipe $london_pipe ) &
   i=0

   while true; do
      if [[ i -gt 100 ]]; then
         echo 'quit' > $madrid_pipe
         echo 'quit' > $berlin_pipe
         break
      else
         echo "loop #$i"
         echo '========='
         message="London loop (#$i)"

         #***send to Madrid***#
         echo "$message" > $madrid_pipe

         read -r answer <&3
         echo 'London says:> '"$answer"

         #***send to Berlin***#
         echo "$message" > $berlin_pipe

         read -r answer <&3
         echo 'London says:> '"$answer"
         (( i++ ))
      fi
   done 3< $london_pipe

   wait
   cd "$DIR"
   rm -rf $london_pipe
   rm -rf $madrid_pipe
   rm -rf $berlin_pipe
}

#a client
function berlin (){
   local i message answer berlin_pipe london_pipe
   berlin_pipe=$1
   london_pipe=$2
   cd $DIR
   i=0
   exec 3> $london_pipe
   while true; do

      read -r answer <&4
      #***if deleted it reads empty strings!!!***#
      if [[ ! $answer ]]; then
         continue
      fi
      echo 'Berlin says:> '"$answer"

      message="Greetings from Berlin!($i)"
      echo "$message" >&3
  (( i++ ))

      if [[ $answer = 'quit' ]]; then
         break
      fi
   done 4< "$berlin_pipe"
}

#another client
function madrid (){
   local i message answer madrid_pipe london_pipe
   madrid_pipe=$1
   london_pipe=$2
   cd $DIR
   i=0
   exec 3> $london_pipe
       while true; do

      read -r answer <&4
      #***if deleted it reads empty strings!!!***#
      if [[ ! $answer ]]; then
         continue
      fi
      echo 'Madrid says:> '"$answer"

      message="Greetings from Madrid!($i)"
      echo "$message" >&3
      (( i++ ))

      if [[ $answer = 'quit' ]]; then
         break
      fi
   done 4< "$madrid_pipe"
}

london
```

The if-code is this block

```
      #***if deleted it reads empty strings!!!***#
      if [[ ! $answer ]]; then
         continue
      fi
```

with this some results are:

```
loop #97
=========
Madrid says:> London loop (#97)
London says:> Greetings from Madrid!(97)
Berlin says:> London loop (#97)
London says:> Greetings from Berlin!(97)
```

without to both clients:

```
loop #91
=========
Madrid says:> London loop (#86)
Madrid says:> London loop (#87)
Madrid says:> London loop (#88)
Madrid says:> London loop (#89)
Madrid says:> London loop (#90)
Madrid says:> 
Madrid says:> 
Madrid says:>
```

it's clear that 'madrid' did read the empty string along with messages from 'london' with loop number 86 etc. which have been pushed by previous empty reads and now being out of order.
Can someone explain this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem is how you write to the pipes in `london`: `echo "$message" > $madrid_pipe`
This opens and closes the pipe for each write, unlike what you do in the other endpoints where you keep the pipes open. This creates a race condition: if `berlin` or `madrid` happen to try reading while the pipe is closed, their reads will return no data, see `man 7 pipe`:

> If all file descriptors referring to the write end of a pipe have been
>   closed, then an attempt to read(2) from  the pipe  will see
>   end-of-file (read(2) will return 0).

The solution is simple enough, either handle this like you did or make sure `london` keeps the pipes open.

Comment: Thanks, I think some things are clarified now.The most important being that the redirection character closes the pipe after! One thing I noticed is that server can initiate clients with jobs just before entering its loop and immediately after entering can start catching the echos of clients without data loss. I thought that the time between asignining jobs and entering the loop a client could write the server's pipe with disaster results because the loop wasn't just opened yet but fortunately data is there! And a last thing is how can 'london' open the pipes it writes to? Can't imagine it!

Comment: The same way berlin and madrid do. Just use an `exec` and then write to the file descriptors in the loop.